# Working with the class keyword in Java

Tags: java, class

I don't really understand how the `class` keywords work in some instances.

For example, the `get(ClientResponse.class)` method takes the  `ClientResponse.class`. How does it use this when it gets it, and what are the advantages over just passing an instance of it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SomeClass.class
```

returns a Java Class object. Class is genericized, so the actual type of SomeClass.class will be `Class<SomeType>` .

There are lots of uses for this object, and you can read the Javadoc for it here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html

Comment: +1 for docs reference. The actual type in runtime however is plain java/lang/Class and it's generic type argument is not preserved due to java generics implementation (type erasure).

Comment: @KrzysztofJabłoński in code if you do `Class clazz = someClass.getClass()` it will ask you to parameterize the variable. is it correct to say that the type will be Class<SomeClass> at compile time but java.lang.Class at runtime?

Comment: Yes. Generics introduced in Java 5 improves type safety at compile time, by introducing so called type parameters. When you're doing some type-risky operations compiler compares type parameters and warns you. In bytecode type parameters are replaced by their [bounds](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) (or Object when none) - so that information is erased. [Paper](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) says that it's done that way in java (unlike for [example C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)).

Answer (score 7):

In `ClientResponse.class`, `class` is not a keyword, neither a static field in the class `ClientResponse`.

The keyword is the one that we use to define a class in Java. e.g.

```
public class MyClass { } /* class used here is one of the keywords in Java */
```

---

The `class` in `ClientResponse.class` is a short-cut to the instance of `Class<T>` that represents the class `ClientResponse`.

There is another way to get to that instance for which you need an instance of `ClientResponse`. e.g

```
ClientResponse obj = new ClientResponse();
Class clazz = obj.getClass();
```

> what are the advantage over just passing a instance of it?

In the above example you can see what would happen in case `obj` was null (an NPE). Then there would be no way for the method to get the reference to the `Class` instance for `ClientResponse`.

Comment: There could also be some dynamic proxying going on as well by something like cglib or javassist.  In addition, it's also possible that you want to work with an interface or abstract class, rather than the actual concrete class type.  By referring to the class directly, you are very specific about what you want.  Also you could be in a context where you don't have an instance to work with:   LogManager.getLogger(MyClass.class)

Answer (score 2):

The `Class` class, which is different from the `class` keyword, is meta-data describing instances.  It tells you about the methods, data members, constructors, and other features of the instances that you create by calling `new`.

> For example get(ClientResponse.class) method takes the
>   ClientResponse.class how does it uses this when it gets it and what
>   are the advantage over just passing a instance of it?

You can't pass an instance of `ClientResponse` to this method; it's expecting meta-data about *all* instances of `ClientResponse`.  If you passed an instance, you'd expect that the method might change the state of that instance.  But passing the meta-data about all instances might allow the method to create a new kind of instance (e.g. a dynamic proxy) or do something else that depends on the meta-data about all instances of `ClientResponse`.  See the difference?

Comment: So as I understood from your post, the `ClientResponse.class` creates an instance of `Class<ClientResponse>`. And from this object we can get all the information about `ClientResponse` class. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

A class is a "blueprint" of the object. The instance is a object.

If we have

```
public class SomeClass {
   int a;
   SomeClass(int a) {
      this.a = a
   }
}
```

We can have an instance of this class

```
SomeClass c = new SomeClass(10);
```

`c` is an instance of the class. It has a integer `a` with value `10`.

The object `SomeClass.class` represents a `Class`.

Here `SomeClass.class` is a `object` of the type `Class` which has the information that `SomeClass` is

1. a **concrete class** with
2. one **constructor**
3. with a **integer member variable**

   and lots more other `metadata` about the class `SomeClass`. Note that it does not have a value for `a`.

You should use `get(c)` incase you are planning to do something with a `instance` of `c` like call `c.a` or other useful functions to manupulate/get data of the instance.

You should use `get(SomeClass.class)` when the get returns something based on the fact that the argument is some type of class. For example, if this is a method on a `Registry` class which has a map which retrieves a `implementation class` based on type of class passed in.

Answer (score 2):

The very most important fact is - you don't need to have an instance to call the method. It's critically useful in situations when you cannot for some reason instantiate a class, e.g. it's abstract, or have only private constructor, or can only be correctly instantiated by some framework, like Spring or JSF.

You can then call `get` to obtain an object of a requested type without even knowing where it does come from and how it get's created.

Answer (score 1):

Here `ClientResponse.class` is an instance of `Class<ClientResponse>`. In general `Class` object represents type of an object. When you create new instance:

```
Object obj = new ClientResponse()
```

you can retrieve the class (type) of that object by calling:

```
obj.getClass()
```

So, why would you pass `Class` objects around? It's less common, but one reason is to allow some method create arbitrary number of instances of a given class:

```
ClientResponse resp = ClientResponse.newInstance();
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of ways Class objects can be used. This is used for Reflection. Below is a link that can help you understand more.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we compile any Java file, the compiler will embed a `public`, `static`, `final` field named `class`, of the type `java.lang.Class`, in the emitted byte code. Since this field is `public` and `static`, we can access it using dotted notation along with class name as in your case it is `ClientResponse.class`.