# Class<T> and class keyword in Java

Tags: reflection, java

I am a little bit confused. Java has some reflection methods to call on `Class<T>` objects.
But I wonder what is the interconnection between `Class<T>` class and `class` keyword in java.

`Class<T>` is just class that uses to represent class itself (methods, fields, annotations) as an object, because everything in java is an object. `class` keyword is used on language level syntax to represent an entity.
When class loader loads class into memory permgen( I know that ther is no such memory area now) ,but to represent class as an object we need an object, so in this case `Class<T>` comes into play.

Am I correct ? Please explain how does it works ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Working with the class keyword in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982717/working-with-the-class-keyword-in-java)

Comment: The bootstrap class loader is used to load such classes : `Class`, `Object` etc.

Comment: The funny thing is that classes are loaded by a `ClassLoader` which is itself a class... That's why a bootstrap class loader (generally written in native code) is necessary. Try `Object.class.getClassLoader()`, it returns null because this classLoader is not written in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: in "imperative" context the property `SomeClass.class` is an instance of `Class<SomeClass>`. The type `Class<SomeClass>` represents the `SomeClass` class as an object (reflection).

Comment: Your initial example could have compiled if you replaced `.class` with `.getClass()` :P

Comment: So I am correct , right ? Class is used just to represent class as an object ?

Comment: Yes. Class<T> is for representing a class as an object. This is the class reflection in Java.

Comment: @e109848 Any Class you write is just a blueprint by which you tell the JVM how to build data objects. Sometimes for complex operations you need to access this blueprint whether to modify it or access one of it's properties (e.g. the path to the class file during runtime). The object representation of this is `Class<T>` where `T` is the name of your class. And you can access this object representation by either the `.class` syntax from the type or the `.getClass()` method from an instance.